# ConnectFour in python: embedding a while loop under a for loop

Tags: python

So I'm trying to implement a ConnectFour game in python, and I'm having some trouble with counting the pieces (from a single player) that are lined up together in a row. My code:

```
    class ConnectFour(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.row=6
    self.col=7
    self.board = []

    #initialize the board
    for arow in range(self.row):
        row = []
        for acol in range(self.col):
            row.append(None)
        self.board.append(row)

    #function for counting the number of the same pieces in a row

    def count_it(self, row, column, step_row, step_col):
    assert row >= 0 and row < 6 and column >= 0 and column < 7
    assert step_row != 0 or step_col != 0
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    if self.board[row][column] == None:
        return 0
    elif self.board[row][column] == 1:
        for i in range(6):
            while self.board[row + (i*step_row)][column + (i*step_col)] == 1:
                counter1 += 1
        return counter1
    else:
        for i in range(6):
            while self.board[row + (i * step_row)][column + (i*step_col)] == 2:
                counter2 += 1
        return counter2
```

When I input a location and "step" in my function, I would like to get the number of pieces player 1 or player 2 has lined up but when I enter:

```
    x= ConnectFour()
    x.board[5][6] = 1  
    x.board[4][6] = 1 

    x.count_it(5,6,-1,0)
```

I get no output.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for that `while` inside `for`: whenever the `while` condition is `true`, it will become an infinite loop since the body of that loop does not affect the condition, it just keeps incrementing a counter forever.

One approach would be a single `while` loop:

```
while self.board[row + (counter1*step_row)][column + (counter1*step_col)] == 1:
    counter1 += 1
```

Another approach is to leave the `for` loop, but `i` and `counter1` actually serve the same purpose:

```
for i in range(6):
    if self.board[row + (i*step_row)][column + (i*step_col)] != 1:
        break
    counter1 += 1
```

In both cases, take care of array boundaries, either by some `if`s, or by placing sentinels at the border of the array.